# Course catch-ups

Tags: grammar

How to name an event, where someone has to go for the classes once again because he/she was unavailable at the time?

Alice missed her swimming pool class tonight.
She has to [catch-up/repeat/work out/???] the classes tomorrow, before the next week exam.

In particular I am interested in the name of this classes:

- catch-up classes
- repeat classes
- work-out classes
- any other ideas...

Comment: A make-up exam or class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class repeated because of a need to improve skills sometimes is called a *remedial*.  As an [adjective](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remedial#Adjective), *remedial* means “intended to correct or improve deficient skills in some subject”.

A session attended because of missing a class is often called a *make-up*, as Mitch remarked.  Here, *make-up* is being used in its *compensatory* sense.  See, for example, wiktionary's sense 3 of *[makeup](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/makeup#Usage_notes)*:  “Replacement; material used to make up for the amount that has been used up”